# Dificuldade para remover item de uma lista invertida no Vue

Tags: javascript, front-end, vue.js-2

Estou apanhando na hora de usar lista no Vue. Exibo na tela uma lista invertida por uma computed. Preciso se exibir ela invertida para quando adicionar um item ele aparecer na parte de cima. Só que da forma que fiz o Vue se perde na hora de remover o item correto da lista.

Veja meu código: https://jsbin.com/jutuyenubi/edit?html,js,console,output

Fiz um botão para adicionar, que funciona corretamente. Já no "remover" eu utilizo o index do item na lista para fazer um splice(), só que o Vue usa esse index na lista invertida, eu imaginei que ele usaria na lista original e depois inverteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tens de usar o index revertido também no argumento dessa função assim:

```
reverse.length - 1 - index
```

Outra maneira seria passar o `id` e depois fazer

```
this.list = this.list.filter(obj => obj.id !== id)
```

ou passar o proprio item:

```
this.list = this.list.filter(obj => obj !== item)
```

Exemplo com o index revertido:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#box',
  data: {
    list: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'item 1'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'item 2'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'item 3'
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    add: function() {
      this.list.push({
        id: 100,
        name: 'novo item'
      })
    },
    del: function(index) {
      alert(index)
      this.list.splice(index, 1)
    }
  },
  computed: {
    reverse: function() {
      return this.list.slice().reverse()
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.3/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">
  <button @click="add">button</button>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(item, index) in reverse">
      {{ item.name }} - <span class="del" @click="del(reverse.length - 1 - index)">remover</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: A sua resposta foi excelente, legal a ideia de usar o filter mas a resposta do @Jozimar Back foi mais simples.

Comment: @FelipeCoelho ótimo, é uma questão de preferência, eu não gosto do `.splice` porque não se aplica a lógica de imutáveis que eu prefiro. Mas a outra resposta é boa  e dei `+1` também :)

Comment: Vc tem razão quanto a questão dos objetos imutaveis, minha aplicação ficou 100% correta utilizando a sua opção.

Answer (score 2):

Olá

As mudanças que eu faria no código seriam adição de propriedade key no html e utilizar próprio item como referencia para remoção:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="box">
    <button @click="add">button</button>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(item, index) in reverse" :key="item.id">
        {{ item.name }} - <span class="del" @click="del(item)">remover</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

E no JS:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#box',
  data: {
    list: [
      {id: 1, name: 'item 1'},
      {id: 2, name: 'item 2'},
      {id: 3, name: 'item 3'}
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    add: function(){
      this.list.push({id: 100, name: 'novo item'})
    },
    del: function(item){
      alert(item.id)
      this.list.splice(this.list.indexOf(item), 1)
    }
  },
  computed: {
    reverse: function(){
      return this.list.slice().reverse()
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Valeu cara, resolveu meu problema.

Comment: Cara a sua resposta funciona, mas é como o Sergio comentou, dá problema com objetos imutáveis. Comecei a ter problemas que foram resolvidos usando a solução do Sergio.